# Stein and Shakarchi potential typo?

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm working through Chapter 6 in Complex Analysis by Stein and Shakarchi, and problem 3 is as follows:

> If $Q(x)=\lbrace x\rbrace-1/2$, then we can write the expression in the previous problem as $$\zeta(s)=\frac{s}{s-1}-\frac{1}{2}-s\int_1^\infty\frac{Q(x)}{x^{s+1}}\mathrm{d}x$$

The expression in the previous problem is $$\zeta(s)=\frac{s}{s-1}-s\int_1^\infty\frac{\lbrace x\rbrace}{x^{s+1}}\mathrm{d}x$$
which I've already shown to be true.  Also, the notation $\lbrace x\rbrace$ denotes the ffractional part of $x$.

My issue is in the $-1/2$ term in the first equation.  Shouldn't it have a factor of $s$ in it?  I just want to make sure that there is a typo before I assume so, as I'd rather not have future work rendered useless by a wrong assumption.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we start with
$$ \zeta(s)=\frac{s}{s-1}-s\int_1^{\infty}\frac{\{x\}}{x^{s+1}}\;dx$$
(with $\Re(s)>0$) and substitute in $\{x\}=Q(x)+\frac{1}{2}$, the result is
$$ \zeta(s)=\frac{s}{s-1}-s\int_1^{\infty}\frac{Q(x)+\frac{1}{2}}{x^{s+1}}\;dx=\frac{s}{s-1}-s\int_1^{\infty}\frac{Q(x)}{x^{s+1}}\;dx-\frac{s}{2}\int_1^{\infty}x^{-s-1}\;dx$$
$$ =\frac{s}{s-1}-\frac{1}{2}-s\int_1^{\infty}\frac{Q(x)}{x^{s+1}}\;dx$$
because
$$ s\int_1^{\infty}x^{-s-1}\;dx=1$$

Comment: Thanks, silly error on my part, glad I checked before I assumed otherwise.